# Filter ngFor by another ngFor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, filter, ngfor

I am developing an app that has to filter the students of a teacher through classes. First I do a ngFor to show in a div all the clases that has the teacher, after I want to add all the students in that class with another ngFor.

The clases are an empty array an the students are objects with different parameters. One of it is the student.class.

Is it possible to filter the students with a ngFor that reads the {{clase}} and {{student.classes}} parameters and only shows the students who match?

The actual code is this:

```
<div *ngFor="let clase of clases">
  <mat-card>
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title>{{clase}}</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let student of students" >  
        <ion-label>
          {{student.first_name}}
        </ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

Thank you very much

Comment: You can filter student list based on class id like this. 
`<ion-label *ngIf="class.id === student.classId">
          {{student.first_name}}
        </ion-label>`
So basically you have to match one key which is common in class and student i.e. **class id**.

Comment: `pipe` is what you want

Comment: Either you use a `pipe`to transform `students` or ... and i think it is the better approach, if you define another view model `interface MyClass{ name: string; strudents: Student[] }`

Comment: I did <ion-label *ngIf="class.id === student.classId">           {{student.first_name}}         </ion-label> and it works to filter the label but I have the problem that it creates empty items when there is no match between the class and the student.class and I cannot use ngFor and NgIf in the same item

Comment: What you say Thomas is to create a [(ngModel)]="clase" and do the students *ngFor like "let student of clase". Is it correct?

Comment: @Sam It's true you can not use ngFor and ngIf with the same element. But you can try `ion-item` under the ngFor.

Comment: Thank you Deep Govani you solved my problem. I change the <ion-item> in the *ngFor to a <div> and the <ion-label> to the actual item with the ngIf so it creates multiple div but only generate items when there is a match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Deep Govany sais in the comments I used *ngIf to filter the *ngFor like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let clase of clases">
  <mat-card>
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title>{{clase}}</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      <div *ngFor="let student of students">  
        <ion-item *ngIf="clase === student.classroom">       
          {{student.first_name}}
        </ion-item> 
      </div>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```